# On ServerSocket, clarification needed

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

We have the declaration

```
public ServerSocket(int port,
                    int backlog)
             throws IOException
```

> Where backlog is identified as the maximum queue length for incoming
>   connection. If a connection indication arrives when the queue is full,
>   the connection is refused.

Lets say backlog is set to 10.

Does this mean `ServerSocket` will `accept` no more then 10 clients?

Followed by:

```
    while (serverShouldStillBeRunning) {
        Socket sock = clientSocket.accept();
        js.new Worker(sock).start();
    }
```

Backlog number will go down only when `sock.close()`. Is this correct?

Is there a way to know how many open connection a socket is currently handling (in other words, how close it is to the point when it gives up and start rejecting new connections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

backlog represents a queue of connections waiting to be processed.

When you `.accept()`, one of those connections has been processed, and is no longer in the queue, so the backlog is reduced by one.